# Prove that every net in a compact and Hausdorff uniform space has a convergent subnet.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have found some proof for just compact spaces, but they are ao complicated, I assume its not so hard but I have a problem working with nets, please help. Thanks

Comment: What is the proof you don't understand?

Comment: That every net in a compact hausdorff uniform space, has a convergent subnet

Comment: Please type out the proof and mention the exact place you get stuck. Also read, [How to ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: The proof i found is just for the compact space and it is not working

Comment: We don't need uniform or Hausdorff, just a compact topological space.

Comment: What proof are *you* referring to (that supposedly doesn't work?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the uniform bit is a red herring. 
In [this note](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/13.pdf) I show that

> A cluster point of a net $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ is exactly the limit of a subnet $(y_j)_{j \in J}$.

No Hausdorff needed, nor uniform notions.

So it suffices to show that every net $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ has a cluster point in a compact space $X$.

Then define for every $i \in I$ the set $T_i = \{x_j: j \ge i\}$, the tail set w.r.t. $i$, where $\le$ is the directed set order on $I$. These are all non-empty, as $x_i \in T_i$ for all $i$.

Then if $T_{i_1}, \ldots T_{i_n}$ are tail sets then the directedness of $(I, \le)$ implies that there is some $j \in I$ such that $i_1, \ldots, i_n \le j$.
But then $T_j \subseteq \bigcap_{k=1}^n T_{i_k}$ from the definitions.

So the set $\{\overline{T_i}: i \in I\}$ is a collection of closed sets of $X$ with the [finite intersection property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_intersection_property).
Hence a standard theorem on compact spaces says that $$\bigcap_{i \in I} \overline{T_i} \neq \emptyset$$

and any point in that intersection is a cluster point of the net (as I show in the linked note (introduction) ), and then there is a convergent subnet to that point by the first fact.

Comment: @Aida I do hope it is more understandable than the proof you refered to.